# Grails maximum number of columns for a table

Tags: grails, grails-orm

There is some strange limit into grails,gorm about the maximum number of columns for a domain class (table)?

In the class definition with 192 columns hibernate create succesfully the table during application boot,with 193 no table is created and no errors in the application log

Comment: look at enabling sqlLogging in your application.yml it is being logged but you need to enable the logging for that

Comment: Sorry,but i return from holiday today. I have done some test and the problem seems to be in the maximum number of varchar(255) fields in the domain class. The maximum number of varchar(255) fields is 85.

Comment: If you want to reproduce it create an empty grails project,add mysql db connection and try to create a domain class with 85 String fields. If you stop with field85 the table is created,with field86 no

Comment: It's a Mysql Problem,with other Db everything works fine. Strange problem,

Comment: Here the Mysql Speficication and the confirm.http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/doc/refman/5.1/en/column-count-limit.html